# SQL query based on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I need to figure out how to make this work in SQL:

If C=1 then find the next row where B is the negative of B in the row where C=1 and the value of A is the same for both rows.  If the difference in D between those 2 rows is greater than 1 day, then return that row where C=1

Sample Data

```
A       B        C        D
1       10.00    0        2015-01-01
1       15.00    1        2015-01-02
1      -15.00    0        2015-01-03
2        5.00    1        2015-01-03
2       -5.00    0        2015-01-05
3        1.00    1        2015-01-03
3        2.00    0        2015-01-04
3       -1.00    0        2015-01-05
```

Expected Output:

```
2        5.00    1        2015-01-03
3        1.00    1        2015-01-03
```

Comment: How do you define "next row"?  SQL table are unordered, so any ordered is defined by a particular column.

Comment: Ok, I should have stated "next row" if we order by D (date) ASC

Answer (score 0):

If by "next" you mean a later value in column d, then you can translate your conditions into an `exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.c = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.d >= datedadd(day, 1, t.d) and t2.a = t.a and
                    t2.b = - t.b
             );
```

Note:  if `b` is a floating point number, you might want a tolerance, something like `abs(t2.b + t.b) < 0.001`.

Comment: Yes, I should have noted that "next" is within the context of "order by D asc"

Answer (score 0):

```
select m1.*
from myTable m1
inner join myTable m2
on m1.a = m2.a                     -- same a
and m1.b = m2.b * -1               -- b is the negative of b
and m1.d < m2.d                    -- the next row
and dateadd(day, 1, m1.d ) > m2.d  -- difference is greater than 1 day
where m1.c = 1

union all 

select m2.*
from myTable m1
inner join myTable m2
on m1.a = m2.a
and m1.b = m2.b * -1
and m1.d < m2.d
and dateadd(day, 1, m1.d ) <= m2.d
where m1.c = 1
```

Comment: "where c = 1" in each select above is ambiguous.  It needs a table name, but I'm not sure if it should be m1.c and m1.c or m1.c and m2.c

Comment: See edit, both are m1.c.  Also notice in the second part I'm selecting m2.* and not m1.*

Answer (score 0):

as one commenter alluded, you have to have some kind of "ordering"....I've introduced an tablekey, you could change the Over/OrderBY to something already existing...but you MUST have some kind of ordering mechanism besides "here they are".

I'm not saying my query is the shortest query...however, when i have "funky business rules", I'll choose a little verbosity over conciseness so if I have to go back and maintain it, I can break down the "parts" somehow that makes sense.

Here is an answer that gets you mostly there.
Basically, I go fishing for the "MagicNewRow" based on your criteria.
But it only works because I was able to create a ComputedRowId off of some ordering mechanism.  (as I explained earlier)

```
declare @holder table (TableKey int identity(1,1) , 
Col1 int, Col2 decimal, Col3 bit , Col4 smalldatetime , ComputedRowID int )
insert into @holder (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
select 1  ,     10.00 ,   0,        '2015-01-01'
union all select 1  ,     15.00,1,        '2015-01-02'
union all select 1  ,    -15.00,    0,        '2015-01-03'
union all select 2  ,      5.00,    1,        '2015-01-03'
union all select 2  ,     -5.00,    0,        '2015-01-05'
union all select 3  ,      1.00,    1,        '2015-01-03'
union all select 3  ,      2.00,    0,        '2015-01-04'
union all select 3  ,     -1.00,    0,        '2015-01-05'

--select * from @holder

Update @holder Set ComputedRowID
= derived1.ROWID
from
@holder hold join

--Select * from
(
select TableKey, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TableKey) as ROWID
from @holder) as derived1
on hold.TableKey = derived1.TableKey
/* 
f C=1 then find the next row where B is the negative of B in the row
 where C=1 and the value of A is the same for both rows. 
 If the difference in D between those 2 rows is greater than 1 day, 
then return that row where C=1*/

;WITH
  cteCIsOne /*Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ROWID )*/
  AS
  (
    Select holderAlias.Col1, holderAlias.Col2, holderAlias.Col3, holderAlias.Col4, holderAlias.ComputedRowID
    from @holder holderAlias
    where Col3 = 1
  )
  ,
    cteRowsGreaterThanCurrentRowIdAndNegRuleApplies /*(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ROWID )*/
  AS
  (
    Select holderAlias.Col1, holderAlias.Col2, holderAlias.Col3, holderAlias.Col4,
     holderAlias.ComputedRowID, 
     MagicNextRowComputedRowID = (select top 1 ComputedRowID from cteCIsOne cte1 
        where holderAlias.ComputedRowID > cte1.ComputedRowID and holderAlias.col2 = (-1 * cte1.col2) )
    from @holder holderAlias
  )

Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 , ComputedRowID , MagicNextRowComputedRowID, MagicNextRowDate
, MyDateDiff = datediff(d, MagicNextRowDate, Col4)
from
(
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 , ComputedRowID , MagicNextRowComputedRowID
,
MagicNextRowDate = (select top 1 Col4 from @holder hold where hold.ComputedRowID = cteAlias2.MagicNextRowComputedRowID)
from cteRowsGreaterThanCurrentRowIdAndNegRuleApplies cteAlias2
) as derived
where derived.MagicNextRowComputedRowID IS NOT NULL 
and
datediff(d, MagicNextRowDate, Col4) > 1
```